# Where does Mail keep its configuration files?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I had to replace my hard drive and don't have a backup. I do have a copy of my home folder on an external disk but it was a simple copy/paste job.

I've been dragging my stuff from that disk to my new drive but I don't know where to look for Mail.app account configuration data. I need to recover the server name, username and password for one of my accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Mail.app stores server credentials in your login keychain. You will find your login keychain in: `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Copy, rename, and open this keychain file with **Keychain Access**. Keychain Access is included with Mac OS X in the **Applications > Utilities** folder.

Within the Keychain Access application, search for your mail server using the search field at the top-right.

To retrieve a password, double-click on the item and enable **Show password:**.

Answer (score 2):

I found the file with the account list under

`~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist`

It seems to hold all sorts of metadata related to accounts but if you go through it you'll find things like server names and ports.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with a twist.

I have some Comcast accounts, and found that they had recently upgraded from POP3 to IMAP. So I had to delete these on my various devices, and re-add them. For some reason, on one of my devices (Macbook Pro, El Capitan), iCloud did not propagate these new accounts, but when I tried to add them manually, I got this error message.

What solved it was:

1. Logging out of iCloud
2. Removing all mentions of accounts from keychain
3. logging in with iCloud.

I don't know if step 2 is required, but it's what I did.

Then when I logged back in, iCloud propagated the accounts.